# Simple Regex Question - I've sat here for close to 4 hours trying to figure this out, and for most of you, it's simple, but not for me

Tags: html, regex, passwords

I know what this site is for, and I've read people griping at others for asking a question like this, but I truly need help, and I've been working on this for a very long time.

I have a huge sheet of passwords and usernames in a .csv file, which I'm trying to format so it can be read by my Google profile (through Google Password Manager). I've tried all different kinds of ways, but Google is picky, and I've had a hell of a time just getting it to register anything except for "failed." I've searched through so many damn forum posts on this site and others. I know I'm almost there, as I finally got an error message, but I just want this to be done, so I finally figured I'd ask all you smart people for help. I've put forth the effort, and I just can't figure it out, just as I can't figure out how to convert any of the examples I find on this site to what I am needing. I've tried, many, many times.

I've used a regex tester to crawl and scrape my way to this:

`/https:\/\/w{3}\.(...+.*\.com|net),?/g`

I'm working on this with Notepad++, so it may be the wrong format. I've been using regex for a while, not really understanding it, which figuring this out above, has helped my understanding a lot.

Below is an edited version of how my document looks, which illustrates most of the issues I am dealing with. I imported it into an excel program, to get all the columns correct and to remove excess (which is how I finally got Google to register an error message).

In Notepad++, I fixed all of the "https://" and all of the variations I had. But for the life of me the hardest thing has been to figure out how to get the "www." on the remaining lines. My code above seems close, but it combines the URL address, with the email address when they are on the same line only separated by a comma, (which combines them into one group) and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to fix it. So, please help.

The top line is how it's organized, except it's in the order of URL, username, and password.

```
username,password,url,
https://www.nvidia.com,myemail@mail.com,password#1,
https://www.google.com,myemail@mail.com,password#2,
https://www.firefox.com,username,password#3,
https://na.alienwarearena.com,myemail@mail.com,password#4,
https://www.pinterest.cl,myemail@mail.com,password#5,
https://www.cplusplus.com,Username,password#6,
https://myaccount.google.com,myemail@gmail.com,password#7,
https://twitter.com,username,password#8,
```

Please, just a simple example of what I'm doing incorrectly, and if you feel like it, a simple explanation, as this has given me a massive headache. But any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Regex may not be needed here, if you just need to reorder the columns you could probably split on ```,``` and get an array of 3 elements. Then just output them in the correct order.

Comment: That is very probable, lol, but I have no clue how to do that. Yet also, doing it this way will help clean up as many erroneous entries I may have.

I'll be checking back, but I'm going to take a break, so I'll be back in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

I might be over-simplifying this a bit much, but sounds like you're just wanting to re-order the columns on the file. Which excel would be the better option (you can just cut/paste the columns around)

But if you want to do this via regex, here's the simplest regex I can think of:

```
^(http[^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXKMua/1)

I'm making the assumption that a `,` will never appear in your data. If it does, then the regex will get much more complex.

```
^             - Forces the regex to start of line
(http[^,]+),  - Matches url. Ensures it starts with http, just so it skips the header. Ends with a comma
([^,]+),      - grabs whatever is between the previous , and the next (which should be the username
([^,]+),?     - grabs the last part, which is the password
```

Each one of the `()` is called a group. When you do a replacement, you can reference these groups. They're numbered left to right starting at `1`.

This allows you to do a find/replace in notepad++. The replacement line will look something like this:

```
$2,$3,$1
```

I'm using sublime and not notepad++. So the replacement might be something like `\2,\3,\1` instead. Can't quite remember how notepad++ works on the replacement.

Best of luck.

Comment: Mock Coder, this answer was exactly what I was hoping for, and for that, thank you so very much. I just read it and haven't tested it, but after my many hours at trying to figure out what you just described, I have no doubt that it is. And after investing so much time trying to figure it out, I'm glad that you explained it to me, which, helps me to understand what I was doing wrong, and trying to figure out. With the code you supplied me just now, I should have no issues finishing this up quickly. As an afterthought, you are probably exactly right about excel being the right program. Thx Again

Comment: I was having some issues when I went to replace a line, it wasn't consistent and sometimes did what I intended, other times it would change the entire line to just one of the groups (not all three). But this is ok, as you reminded me of using different editors which are extremely customizable, and while I don't have enough to purchase Sublime, I went with Atom (which I've used before and really like). After checking the addons, I found tons and tons of good resources and guides about regex. So, after a couple of years of using regex and not understanding it, I'm about to take a crash course.

Comment: Good to hear you're taking the dive. The regex is fairly simple so it will probably have to do with where the `,` are. If the line is missing or has extra commas it would definitely mess up. Check out [Regex Info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you haven't already, it helped me when I was trying to better understand regexs. Happy to help out if you can share a line where it's messing up. Good luck.

Comment: I definitely will, but I like to try to figure as much out as I can on my own (gotta learn somehow). And with Atom, really, it makes it basically regex for dummies, as you don't really have to know anything. But, the more I do it, the more I'll understand and remember it. Thanks again Mock.

Comment: Yet, I now understand what you were saying about the commas, I don't know for sure if I need them or not, but I think I do. Your code works perfectly, unless I need to keep those damn commas.